# Return .plist from .NET WCF4 Web Service

Tags: iphone, wcf, .net-4.0, plist

I recently listened to the WWDC 2010 discussion Session 117 - Building a Server-driven User Experience.  The presenter discussed the performance difference between processing XML vs. JSON vs. plist.  plist was much faster and about the same size as XML (worse than JSON, but much faster processing).

I am wondering if anyone knows of a library for putting together/formatting a plist for return from a .NET 4 WCF service.

Currently, I am using www.sudzC.com to generate proxy classes from my .asmx wsdl web services for use in my iPhone application, but we are starting to move to a WCF environment in hopes of being able to abstract data layer interaction from presentation.  I am hoping that I can return any client it's favorite data format.

Let me know.

Thanks in advance!
Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out plist.net it at least will create the plist for you.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/plistdotnet/

Comment: That should do the trick, although I am concerned about how infrequently it is downloaded or worked on.  It looks like there are a couple of projects on CodePlex, as well, but they are downloaded too often either (although a little more recently uploaded).  http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=plist&sortBy=Relevance&tagName=%2cplist%2c&licenses=|&refinedSearch=true